Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS poor microphone input quality
Im on Lenovo thinkpad T14s, microphone under windows 11 was ok, after installing ubuntu (and removing windows parition) microphone is just trash, anything it records is too quiet and if i increment its volume it helps a tiny bit, but now there are echoes. Im not sure what to do, after some research drivers for my sound card are apparently in linux kernel since ubuntu version 18.
some dumps
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: acp63 [acp63], device 0: DMIC capture dmic-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0



$ amixer -c0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]

alsa-info http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=488b0419228d268cbda38a2cb6d9fb6056bac1c7
Any help is greatly appretiated
